# When inserting a lot of data : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working on a React and Django API project, I'm using postgreeSQL as Database, and I deployed my website using nginx and gunicorn,

I have a problem on my deployed website when I try to insert a lot of data (add studies),
I'm getting this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.85.126:8000/api/new-study/' 
from origin 'http://192.168.85.126' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

PS: I'm not getting this error when I try to add less data, in my development environment I can add whatever data I want, the problem is only happening in production

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you're not using gunicorn in your development environment, but only use `manage.py runserver`, aren't you? That's why it was running, as "development server" is more easy and loose on security than gunicorn.

This is a security issue, as your system is blocking request from an unknown origin:

- Your server: http://192.168.85.126:8000
- The request origin: http://192.168.85.126 <<< no port, so it is considered different server

To fix the issue, in the settings.py, add the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS parameter like this
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://192.168.85.126:8000', 'http://192.168.85.126']

Furthermore, if you're going to use SSL later (https), then you will also have to add CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS for each https server

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work, it is not a problem of blocking the origin, everything work in my API I can get data and everything, I can add data (a few amount of data), but when it it is a lot of data that require more time to be added, I get the error